# How To Receive Real Time Latitude and Longitude In Django and DRF

Tags: django, google-maps, django-rest-framework, geolocation, geodjango

I am trying to make an endpoints where by I can get the longitude and latitude of a User(Rider) in Real Time and save it to my Database. I have tried Researching about how to go about this, but I have only been able to get How to receive the current location which isn't in real-time as I want. I would be glad if anyone could directs me on how to go about this and provide some materials where i could read more about how to achieve this or a past work on this.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You need use WebSockets. https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean, getting live location is a front end matter that then sends it to the BackEnd so you need to check out how to enable user location access in the library you're using in your front (react,react native,vue...)
if you then later need to convert address or lat/long back and fourth I recommned starting with the Google Maps API, you'll need to generate an API Key in that dasboard (free use to certain limit)

then you can use it to get certain data about a location, for example, get it's elevation:

```py
RESULTS = 'results'
LOCATIONS = '?locations='
KEY = '&key='
INDEX: int = 0
LOCATIONS = 'Locations'
def get_elevation(lat: float, lon: float):
    """
    This function receives a Point and sends a request to Google's Elevation API.
    @param float lat: latitude
    @param float lon: longitude
    @return float: elevation of point in meters
    """

    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json"

    request = urlopen(url + LOCATIONS + str(lat) + "," + str(lon) + KEY + _GOOGLE_API_KEY)
    results = json.load(request).get(RESULTS)
    elevation = 0.0
    if INDEX < len(results):
        elevation = results[INDEX].get(ELEVATION)
        print(elevation)
    return elevation
```

It can also be used to retrieve an address from lat long and vice versa and so on..

you can also keep a model like so in your app:

```py
class GeoLocation(models.Model):
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=10, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=10, null=True, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=country_names.items(), blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.street}, {self.city}, {self.country}'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # this is just an example use
        if all([self.street, self.city, self.country]) is None:
            # haven't implemented a function like this myself but it just a way to use thie model
            self.street, self.city, self.country = get_address_from_lat_long(self.latitude, self.longitude)
        elif all([self.latitude, self.longitude]) is None:
            # using the str(self) will return the full address, which google maps has endpoint for
            self.latitude, self.longitude = get_lat_long_from_address(str(self))
```

Comment: I am not actuallly using any frontend library. I will try Rephrasing my question. I will to get a users location and also the user is not in a fised position, he is constantly moving till he gets to the final location. I want to get the latitude and longitude for every seconds the user moves as an endpoint.

Comment: then as stated earlier, you'll have to open a WebSocket using Django Channels, if this the only use of the app I recommend switching to a small and lighter framework that can  handle this stuff more easily like FastAPI ( which has a very easy and awesome WebSocket)

Comment: Alright Sir, But its not the only use of the app as I am integrating it into my current web application. Will FastApi be able to do that also